# ASP.NET Core Options Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the Options Pattern described [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects), but I'm wanting to be able to get something more complex than just key/value pairs.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to copy my appsettings.json using the `Paste JSON as Classes`, and then hand off the root class to `services.Configure<T>(Configuration)` and be done with it.

Here's what I've done:

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionA": {
      "ConnectionString": "string1"
    },
    "ConnectionB": {
      "ConnectionString": "string2"
    }
  }
}
```

**corresponding classes**

```
public class Data
{
    public Connectiona ConnectionA { get; set; }
    public Connectionb ConnectionB { get; set; }
}

public class Connectiona
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class Connectionb
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<Data>(Configuration);
```

This returns null objects for `ConnectionA` and `ConnectionB` though.

Any suggestions?

**full startup.cs per request:**

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<Data>(Configuration);

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Edit**:

This works:

```
services.Configure<Data>(options => {
    options.Connectiona = new Connectiona();
    options.Connectiona = new Connectionb();
    options.Connectiona.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:Connectiona:ConnectionString"];
    options.Connectionb.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:Connectionb:ConnectionString"];
});
```

So it looks like I just can't use the `services.Configure<Data>(Configuration)` extension.

Comment: Your Json is not well formatted. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: A typo here only, sorry.

Comment: Also did you include `services.AddOptions();` first during your setup

Comment: Show your full startup. You may have left out adding the appsettings.json file

Comment: @Nkosi I did not have it, but I added it. Added the file. The connections are used in a separate project, which is why the DbContexts aren't added here. Also, AddOptions() didn't help :(

Comment: @Nkosi, please see the edit.

Comment: @Charles try `services.Configure<Data>(Configuration.GetSection("Data"));`

Comment: That worked, if you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `services.Configure<Data>(Configuration.GetSection("Data"));` instead of `services.Configure<Data>(Configuration);`

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DataWarehouseConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "yourconnectionstringhere"
    },
    "DefaultConnection ": {
      "ConnectionString": "yourconnectionstringhere"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I have... I just didn't copy the names from that file (since it had sensitive info), and I did from the classes file. I'll update the example.